# Using plyr (or *apply) to calc cumulative rtns

Tags: r, plyr

I've struggled for hours on this problem that seems right for plyr or *apply.  Can someone point me to a less clunky R solution than the one I've listed below?

Bkdg: I looked at many R finance related packages, and I can't find a popular package that deals well with securities that disappear in the middle of a time series along with weights that vary programatically.  I'm building my own solution for this particular issue, but I'd rather use an existing one.

The crux of the problem is that I want to use plyr to "loop" over a list of securities within a date subset.  Some of the securities disappear over the date range.  (I'm using forward rtns from data tha is free of survivorship bias.)  I want the output from each date range to be a data frame of cumulative returns of the selected securities. I can use this (along with initial weights) to combine with other date ranges to calculate various portfolio metrics.

I start with a (toy) data frame of selected securities like this (date, ticker, net return):

```
d                t    r
1 2013-03-31   ibm 0.01
2 2013-03-31  appl 0.02
3 2013-03-31 loser 0.03
4 2013-04-30   ibm 0.04
5 2013-04-30  appl 0.05
6 2013-04-30 loser 0.06
7 2013-05-31   ibm 0.07
8 2013-05-31  appl 0.08
```

Note that security "loser" is not present in the last month of the date range.  (Securities will not reappear.)  Here is some code that creates the toy data frame and the clunkly solution that seems to work.

```
library(plyr)
#Create data frame for the example code
dt <- as.Date("20130331","%Y%m%d")
mydf <- data.frame(d=dt,t="ibm",r=0.01)
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="appl",r=0.02))
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="loser",r=0.03))
dt <- as.Date("20130430","%Y%m%d")
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="ibm",r=0.04))
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="appl",r=0.05))
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="loser",r=0.06))
dt <- as.Date("20130531","%Y%m%d")
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="ibm",r=0.07))
mydf <- rbind(mydf,data.frame(d=dt,t="appl",r=0.08))
#Note that there is no row for "loser" for 2013-05-31

#This plyr call crashes because "loser" doesn't have the same 
#   num of rtns as the others
#newdf <- ddply(mydf,.(t),function(x) cumprod(x[,"r"]+1)-1)
```

**Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")):** 
**Results do not have equal lengths**

```
#I work with intermediate lists as a workaround
tmp.list <- dlply(mydf,.(t),function(x) cumprod(x[,"r"]+1)-1)

#Get the longest of any of the resulting lists (tmp = 3 in this example)
tmp <- max(as.numeric(lapply(tmp.list,length))) 

#Define function to extend cumulative rtn for missing values
#   By holding cumulative rtn constant, its as if
#   I hold cash when a security disappears
extendit <- function(x) if(length(x)<tmp){ 
  c(x,rep(x[length(x)],tmp-length(x)))
} else {x}

#Use plyr to make all lists the same length
tmp2.list<-llply(tmp.list,extendit)

#Use plyr to create the data table I wanted
cusipcumrtns.df <- ldply(tmp2.list)          

#Must name key column since it got lost in the process
colnames(cusipcumrtns.df)[1] <- "t"
```

The code above yields the following data frame containing the cumulative returns for each security.

```
t         V1     V2       V3
1   ibm 0.01 0.0504 0.123928
2  appl 0.02 0.0710 0.156680
3 loser 0.03 0.0918 0.091800
```

Any pointers for a more refined solution are greatly appreciated.  This seems to work, but I'm trying to learn to be a better with R.

Comment: Your end result is equivalent to saying that `loser` had a zero return (no win, no loss) on its missing period. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @flodel: Yes, I think so.  Since I'm using what I am told is a data set free of survivorship bias, I am assuming that the forward rtn from the last period contains any returns due to bankruptcy or acquisition or whatever.  Rather than reinvest the proceeds in the other securities, I hold cash.  I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do, but it is what I intended.  I welcome your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9996566/1201032, you could add missing rows to your data:

```
keys.df <- expand.grid(d = unique(mydf$d),
                       t = unique(mydf$t))
full.df <- merge(keys.df, mydf, all.x = TRUE)
```

Then use what you originally had in mind, but make sure to turn missing returns into zeroes (as we commented about):

```
ddply(full.df, .(t), function(x) cumprod(ifelse(is.na(x$r), 0, x$r) + 1) - 1)
      t   V1     V2       V3
1   ibm 0.01 0.0504 0.123928
2  appl 0.02 0.0710 0.156680
3 loser 0.03 0.0918 0.091800
```

You might also consider keeping your output in a long format:

```
ddply(full.df,.(t), transform, cum.r = cumprod(ifelse(is.na(r), 0, r) + 1) - 1)
```

Comment: Much nicer.  Now I have to study this for a few minutes!  Thanks!