# Add missing rows with NA in long (time series) data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

Let's suppose I have an incomplete `data.frame` in long form:

```
mydata <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2000,2001,2002,2004),
                                2),
                     team = factor(c("A","A","A","A",
                                     "B","B","B","B")),
                     score = c(8,1,3,1,2,3,7,2))
```

As you can see, the observations for the `year` 2003 are missing:

```
mydata

   year team score
 1 2000    A     8
 2 2001    A     1
 3 2002    A     3
 4 2004    A     1
 5 2000    B     2
 6 2001    B     3
 7 2002    B     7
 8 2004    B     2
```

**Is there an elegant way to add the missing rows (at the right place)**?

I want the `team` variable to be filled withh all possible levels and `score` with `NA`...

I would prefer a clean `dplyr` solution if there is one (-;

In the end `mydata` should look like this:

```
   year team score
1  2000    A     8
2  2001    A     1
3  2002    A     3
4  2003    A    NA
5  2004    A     1
6  2000    B     2
7  2001    B     3
8  2002    B     7
9  2003    B    NA
10 2004    B     2
```

[This `expand.grid` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996452/r-find-and-add-missing-non-existing-rows-in-time-related-data-frame) almost solves the problem, but I don't know how to apply it to a  `data.frame` in long form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `complete()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(team) %>% 
  complete(year = full_seq(year, 1))
 #1      A  2000     8
 #2      A  2001     1
 #3      A  2002     3
 #4      A  2003    NA
 #5      A  2004     1
 #6      B  2000     2
 #7      B  2001     3
 #8      B  2002     7
 #9      B  2003    NA
#10      B  2004     2
```